# PHP Warning: Use of undefined constant

Tags: php, wordpress

Сервер постоянно логирует вот такую ошибку:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant cz2_customer_form_callback - assumed 'cz2_customer_form_callback' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/jadech/www/jade.ch/wp-content/plugins/clubzone/plugin.php on line 33

```
function cz2_customer($text) {

return preg_replace_callback("|\[czCustomer(.*)\]|", cz2_customer_form_callback, $text); }

function cz2_customer_form_callback($options) {

$config = array();



if (count($options) == 2) {

    $options = explode(" ", $options[1]);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($options); $i++) {

        if (empty($options[$i])) continue;

        list($k, $v) = explode("=", trim($options[$i]));

        $config[$k] = $v;

    }

}



echo cz2_customer_form(array("form") + $config);
```

}

Comment: Функция preg_replace_callback вторым параметром просит имя callback-функции. Оберните cz2_customer_form_callback в кавычки и всё будет хорошо.

Comment: Да, проблема ушла. Спасибо!